# Simple command line client for the Google App Engine datastore

Tags: java, google-app-engine, command-line, compiler-construction, autocomplete

We have recently [created a tool](https://github.com/inpun/gaecl) which allows to talk to Google App Engine via command line, like that:

```
> print KEY("Domain", "mycustomer.com")
{
  "domainAdmin" : "admin@mycustomer.com",
  "maxNbUsers" : 12,
  "trialExpires" : "2013-05-31 12:43:02",
  "status" : "ACTIVE"
}
```

This is an SQL-like command line application which allows to work with Google Datastore without writing code in Python/Java/Go/PHP.

The problem is that this tool does not save history of previous commands. You have to enter them manually every time.

I wonder if there is a wrapper which could remember history of commands which were passed to a child Java process? Or may be there is an even smarter way to add history file support for this application?

Comment: Sounds like your are on the right thought track. Implement a class that is called first, in that class save the command (and recognize characters to go up / down to previous command stack). Once the command is chosen or entered, call your original method to process the command.  You can develop the "command line stacking" class seperately (just debugging going up / down and new command) .. once that works, you can then hook it to your current program

Comment: Have you ever tried to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The ReadLine part of jmxsh with its History support looks right for this job.  It mentions jline dependencies, so your mileage may vary.  http://java-readline.sourceforge.net/ and https://code.google.com/p/jmxsh/source/browse/trunk/src/jmxsh/Readline.java